# didReceiveRemoteNotification and modal views

Tags: ios, delegates, push-notification, modalviewcontroller

My app delegate has a RootViewController *viewController; and the app launches with this view.

From here on I will continue to present modal views (up to 3 levels) as the user navigates to different functions within the app.

I have setup the app to receive push notifications, and I have didReceiveRemoteNotification inside the app delegate to retrieve the payload.

Now the questions:

1. When the push notification is received, how can I know which modal view the user is currently in?
2. How do I close all the modal views to return to the RootViewController? Can I actually do this within the app delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic built-in way of doing this. The best solution is probably to add a property to your app delegate where you can store it.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *currentModalViewController;
```

When you present modal view controllers, do this:

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

// ....
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.currentModalViewController = vc;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

You also need to make sure you lose the reference when dismissing:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAimated:YES];
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.currentModalViewController = nil;
```

Then in your app delegate, you have everything you need in order to dismiss the current modal view controller and check if there is a modal view controller present at the moment.